# Vim spell highlighting

Tags: vim

I want to change vim cyan highlighting, like on **Autocompletion** word:

[image]

Please note, only change, do not remove.

I've already changed red highlighting for **SpellBad** to underline with the next settings:

```
hi clear SpellBad
hi SpellBad cterm=underline
```

But the same strategy for **SpellRare** doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think you should get your question migrated to [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you using `gvim` or command line `vim`?

Comment: dlmeetei, command line vim

Comment: @VladHatko There are other highlight groups containing the keyword `spell` in their name. To list them, you can type `:hi *spell*`, then hit `C-d` (`control`+`d`; not `Enter`). On my machine, it lists `SpellBad`, `SpellCap`, `SpellLocal`, `SpellRare`. Maybe you need to change one of them. If for some reason, your changes are not taken into account, they may be overwritten by a plugin. To see where a highlight group was last defined, you can use the `:verbose` modifier. For example: `:verb hi spellrare`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help from [user852573](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8243465/user852573) I finally get it to work. My mistake was setting **SpellRare**, instead of **SpellLocal**.

Currently my .vimrc looks like this:

```
 hi clear SpellBad                                                
 hi SpellBad cterm=underline                                      
 hi clear SpellRare                                               
 hi SpellRare cterm=underline                                     
 hi clear SpellCap                                                
 hi SpellCap cterm=underline                                      
 hi clear SpellLocal
 hi SpellLocal cterm=underline
```

And an entire editor free from this highlighting.